# PHP MYSQL Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql

Following is my code, `$data[0]->persinId` passed from angularjs POST request

```
$idPerson=$data[0]->persinId;
$StmtQuestionType=connect_db()->query('SELECT a.`question_id` FROM answer a WHERE a.`person_id`=:PersonId');
$StmtQuestionType->bindValue(':PersonId',$idPerson);
$StmtQuestionType->execute();
```

but i am getting following err

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':PersonId' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\survey\insert.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\survey\insert.php(11): PDO->query('SELECT a.`quest...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\survey\insert.php on line 11
```

Comment: `prepare` instead of `query`?

Comment: `query()` executes the given query immediately. Instead you want to use `prepare()`, then `bind()`, then `execute()`...

Comment: Replace `$StmtQuestionType=connect_db()->query('SELECT a.`question_id` FROM answer a WHERE a.`person_id`=:PersonId');`  with `StmtQuestionType=connect_db()->prepare('SELECT a.`question_id` FROM answer a WHERE a.`person_id`=:PersonId');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace:

```
$StmtQuestionType=connect_db()->query('SELECT a.`question_id` 
                                FROM answer a WHERE a.`person_id`=:PersonId');
```

with:

```
$StmtQuestionType=connect_db()->prepare('SELECT a.`question_id` 
                                FROM answer a WHERE a.`person_id`=:PersonId');
```

You needed to first "prepare", not "query" since you are using a prepared statement with named placeholders.